# Change font-size of SELECTED text in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a working drop-down list that allows me to change the font-size of the words inside my contenteditable div. However, it affects the **entire** contenteditable, instead of just the selected text.

```
        <select onchange="$('#editor1').css('font-size', event.target.value + 'px')">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: I've tried the code there, it's still not working. Here's the javascript I used:   function select(){
  {       
  var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
  var span= document.createElement("span");
  span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  span.appendChild(selectedText);
  selection.insertNode(span);
  }

This is my button: 
   <button class="highlight" onclick="select()" title="Highlight Selected Text"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square" style="font-size:1.8em" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, it's really messy. What do you mean it's not working

Comment: Fixed it, sorry. Thanks for the link!

Comment: No problem, in the future, it's better to search up these questions before asking